# console warrnings and errors on headless chrome in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, console-application, google-chrome-headless, windows-console

i'm creating a desktop application with **selenium** and **python**..
this app gets some data from my website with selenium .. it works fine without any problems untill i tried to run chrome in **headless mode** .. like that:

```
opt = Options()
opt.add_argument("--headless")
cpanel_window = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe", options=opt)
cpanel_window.get(mywebsite)
```

it works fine but in the **console** there are werid messages appear after sometime..

> > [1016/142332.539:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of null", source: https://eaalim.examhelper.org/js/lavalamp.js (2)
> >
> > [1016/142337.343:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://eaalim.examhelper.org/cpanel/SendInvoice_1To1.aspx?coursecode=SB22496&back_sid=8969&back_g=All&back_type=s' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://eaalim.examhelper.org/emailtemplates/responsive/images/Icon-responsive.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.", source: https://eaalim.examhelper.org/cpanel/fckeditor/editor/fckeditor.html?InstanceName=ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder3%24txtemail&Toolbar=Default (0)
> >
> > [1016/142337.344:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://eaalim.examhelper.org/cpanel/SendInvoice_1To1.aspx?coursecode=SB22496&back_sid=8969&back_g=All&back_type=s' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://eaalim.examhelper.org/emailtemplates/responsive/images/logo.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.", source: https://eaalim.examhelper.org/cpanel/fckeditor/editor/fckeditor.html?InstanceName=ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder3%24txtemail&Toolbar=Default

the application doesn't stop but those messages are really annoying because i print the steps and reports in console so i need it clean..
is there any way to avoid or hide those messages ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might need to add a few additional `Options` to Chromedriver to bypass the warnings.

For headless mode, I also add `--disable-gpu` and `--window-size=1920,1200` to set the proper window size for my tests -- if the browser is too small, elements will render differently. `--disable-gpu` is recommended by chromedriver devs [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome).

You may also want to add `--no-sandbox` and `--allow-insecure-localhost` to help with the HTTPS errors you are seeing.

Added by the original asker: To hide the Javascript warnings you are seeing, you can set `--log-level=3`

Comment: ty so much Christine..
now i know how to deal with it

Comment: well there's alot of problem in this website not just javascript codes ..
is there any way to disable that javascript error from showing in console ?

Comment: In Selenium, I am not sure if that's possible. The real solution is to have the website not run Javascript that is broken. There aren't any Selenium solutions unless you disable Javascript completely, which will probably break the page under test.

Comment: Finaly!! .. 
"--log-level=3" this parameter solved the problem for me  >>>

'Sets the minimum log level. Valid values are from 0 to 3: INFO = 0, WARNING = 1, LOG_ERROR = 2, LOG_FATAL = 3. <<< 
i set it to 3 so it passes the warnings and errors ^_^

Comment: Good one! I'll add it to the answer in case others need to see it in the future too.